# Is a circular linked list (of a finite set of nodes) considered to be an infinite list?

Tags: linked-lists

So, a circular linked list is a linked list where the next pointer of the last node points to the first node (forming a circle).

Now, a linked list comes with some standard methods, like size()/length(), toArray(), or traverse() (print out the nodes).

Clearly, the implementation of the above (and related) methods, depends on whether a circular linked list is assumed to be infinite or not, I think. For example, its size/length should be infinity if the list itself is assumed to be infinite.

However, I do not know what the general assumption is in this case (if it exists).

Comment: No. See also [Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_tortoise_and_hare).

Comment: @PålGD thanks, I am of the same opinion actually, but I could see the argument go both ways.